# Scope of root in kivy language

Tags: python, kivy

What is the scope of **root** if I have a custom widget embedded in another custom widget? Is there a rule of thumb to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 1):

`root` in a kv rule refers to the top level widget in that rule, e.g.

```
<SomeWidget>:
    text: 'test'
    Label:
        text: root.text + ' test'  # root refers to the top-level SomeWidget instance
```

Answer (score 0):

root is global to every widget rule and refers to the top most widget which in most cases is the instance of the class...